# How can you initialize an entire array at once in GML?

Tags: arrays, initialization, game-maker, gml, game-maker-language

I want to initialize an entire array at once but I can't find any examles of this being done anywhere.

I want to do something like this:

```
int a [][] = {{0,1,0},
              {0,1,1},
              {2,1,0}};
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately GML is not like many other languages in the sense that GML does not have single line array initialization. You can easily write a script to accomplish this, but the GML docs use this method to initialize arrays. The example they gave initializes a 10 record array (0-9) with zeros.

```
var i;
i = 9;
repeat(10)
   {
   array[i] = 0;
   i -= 1;
   }
```

If you want different values for every record then you have to manually type every position. This is the example the docs gave.

```
count = 3;
array[count] = "you?"
count -= 1;
array[count] = "are "
count -= 1;
array[count] = "How "
count -= 1;
array[count] = "Hello!"
count -= 1;
```

In regards to a script: Here is a simple one for 1D arrays. Used as `var myArray = array(record 1, record 2, 3, 4, ...)`

```
///array(*args);
var arr;
for (var i=0;i<argument_count;i+=1)
{
    arr[i] = argument[i];
}
return arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a current version of GameMaker, there's array literal syntax in form of `[...items]` ([documentation](http://docs2.yoyogames.com/source/_build/3_scripting/3_gml_overview/10_arrays.html)). So you can do

```
a = [[0,1,0],
     [0,1,1],
     [2,1,1]];
```

and that'll work fine.

The only thing to note that this'll produce an array of arrays (which is how arrays work in most languages) rather than GML-specific legacy 2d array, so you'd need to use a pair of `[index]` accessors rather than `[index1, index2]`.